Regex for a comma separated text with optional double quotes that can contain backslash-escaped quotes
I need a regular expression that can separate a string like:
1st, 2nd=second, "3rd=third","4th = forth",,"6th=\"this, is, the, sixth\""

into
1st         // not surrounded
2nd=second  // not surrounded
3rd=third   // surrounded
4th = forth // surrounded, keep the blank in the middle
            // empty string
6th="this, is, the, sixth"    // the scaped dbl-quotes and commas in the middle should be kept

notice that if the sections do not have comma or dbl-quotes, they may or may not be surrounded, but if they have special characters, they should be surrounded, and double quotes must be scaped with a backslash. Also, empty values (like the 5th one) should be kept.Any help would be appreciated.

Don’t use regex for parsing CSV. Regex to split a csv and Can the csv format be defined by a regex?

Maybe something like (?|"([^\\"]*(?:\\.[^\\"]*)*)"|([^,]+|(?<=,)|^(?=,))) (get the captures of first group, the \n in the demo is just for multiline-showcase)

This is a straightforward scan if you don't use regular expressions. Start at the start. Search for the next comma or quote. If you found a quote, search for the next quote and skip the subsequent comma. Repeat until done. Is there a reason that you want to make it harder?  Regular expressions are almost never the right solution to a parsing problem. In the last ten years I've only seen two questions on SO where a regular expression might be a good solution; I've seen dozens where it was definitely far more complicated than just writing the obvious code.

@PeteBecker: One minor addition: you can embed a double quote in a string by using two in a row, so something like "He said: ""hi, my name is Jerry""" is a single string containing two double quotes (but yes, if anything this makes a regex even more complex, while having little effect on straightforward code).

General-purpose CSV is significantly more complicated to read than people realize, unless you make restrictions (like no binary data in fields, or newlines in fields, or requiring only a subset variant, etc). That said, a (relatively simple) automaton is absolutely the best way to construct a CSV reader. And that said, best search for a CSV reader library. There are quite a few for both C and C++.

@Sam I had overflooked optional space before and after the quoted parts. If this can happen, better use (?|\h*"([^\\"]*(?:\\.[^\\"]*)*)"\h*|([^,]+|(?<=,)|^(?=,))) (I added \h* to my last pattern at the appropriate positions for any amount of horizontal space)

@bobblebubble your answer looks pretty good. I wish people were not so quick to close the question (specially when what they are sighting does not address all the concerns) so I could accept your answer.

@WiktorStribiżew The linked duplicate target is not for backslash-escaped quotes but for doubled double-quotes and also rather for splitting than matching. However I reopened to post my answer.

For your provided samples the following regex would suffice.
(?|\h*"([^\\"]*(?:\\.[^\\"]*)*)"\h*|([^,]+|(?<=,)|^(?=,)))

See this demo at regex101 (the \n in the demo is just for multiline showcase)
It's using a branch reset group to capture the desired parts by the same first group which is supported by PCRE and even boost regex (added to its ECMAScript grammar in version 1.42).
With this pattern the following cases are covered (alternated, priority from left to right)

\h*"([^\\"]*(?:\\.[^\\"]*)*)"\h* capture what's inside quoted parts surrounded by \h* any amount of horizontal space - containing any amount of escaped quotes.
[^,]+ parts without quotes: One or more characters that are not a comma.
(?<=,) any remaining empty spaces preceded by a comma (lookbehind).
^(?=,) if there is an empty space at the ^ start of the string/line, e.g. ,a

Generelly it's recommended to use a csv-parser if one is available in your environment.
